# pick<> type of array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to construct type `{name:string,value:string}` from another type `Todo`.

Below code throws error: Property '0' does not exist on type 'Pick<Todo, "items">'.

```js
type Todo = {
  title: string;
  items:Array<{name:string,value:string}>;
  description: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
 
type TodoItems = Pick<Todo, "items">[0]; //ERROR: Property '0' does not exist on type 'Pick<Todo, "items">'.
 
const todo: TodoItems = {
  name: "Clean room",
  value: "yes",
};
```

> Note: `Todo` comes from a `ts` module so it's not editable.

What approach could I follow to extract `{name:string,value:string}` from `Todo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to split Todo item into separate type as Dmitrii Zolotuhin said, it will be the rightest way. BUT if you can't do it, you can create this type

```
type TodoItems = Todo["items"][number]
// ...or
type TodoItems = Pick<Todo, "items">["items"][number]
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gEzlAvFA3gKClYBLYAGwgC4oBnYAJzwDsBzAbmygIgFtyyBBKqgQxAAedFFr92pSjQYAaAG79CAVynU69KAF8AfCwQRyAYxph8cWmWkbmOI3HZhiwCAjIAjOHGL9azLdiYoJCwiHAAki6cqKFIANoARGycCQC6cbTK7O4QVKmB9rSUuGFk8EiRHOQxWDjikmQA5OSNsiyKKqRQAEyyUAD0-VC5VHBUmFqMQA)

Answer (score 2):

You were almost right, try `type TodoItems = Todo["items"][0];`

```
type Todo = {
  title: string;
  items:Array<{name:string,value:string}>;
  description: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
 
type TodoItems = Todo["items"][0]; 
//...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=35&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gEzlAvFA3gKClYBLYAGwgC4oBnYAJzwDsBzAbmygIgFtySBBKqgQxAAedLX7tSlGgwA0AN36EArpOp16AXwB8zHAgjkAxjTD44tMlPW6ohuOzDFgEBGQBGcOMX61mG7JigkLCIcACSzpyoIUgA2gBEbJzxALqxAAwpjFABdrSUuKFk8EgRHOTRWDhiEmTxAMLetFBUnuzxMiwKyqRQ8SAGHZgajEA)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the other way:

```js
interface TodoItem {
    name: string
    value: string
}

interface Todo {
    title: string
    items: TodoItem[]
    description: string
    completed: boolean
}

const todo: TodoItem = {
    name: "Clean room",
    value: "yes",
}
```

Comment: thanks for alternative solution but due to some constraints I want to extract type of array from an existing type.